# Is the integral $\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x(e^x-e^{-x})}}}$ convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to prove that $\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x(e^x-e^{-x})}}}$ is convergent. First of all, the only problematic point is zero. I noticed that since $e^x$ is a growing function and $e^{-x}$ is a decreasing function, then $e^x-e^{-x}$ must have only one root- at the point zero. For all $x>0$ $e^x-e^{-x}>0$. But then what? I can't think of a function that is bigger or lower than the integral function. If I try with Taylor series, I get:

- $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+...$
- $e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-...$

Since the problem is at zero, only the lowest degree matters. So $e^{x}\sim 1+x$ and $e^{-x}\sim 1-x$, therefore $\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x(e^x-e^{-x})}}}\sim \int_0^1{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{2x^2}}}$, which is convergent. Therefore $\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x(e^x-e^{-x})}}}$ is also convergent. Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e^x-e^{-x}=2\sinh x\ge2x\qquad(x\ge0)$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt[3]{x(e^x-e^{-x})}}\,dx\le\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt[3]{2x^2}}\,dx<\infty$$

Comment: I haven't studied hyperbolic functions yet but your answer was helpful nevertheless. Thank you!